# Sharing Laptop WLAN through Ethernet with a Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, windows

I want to share my wlan from my laptop (win10) with my Raspberry Pi, that is connected with the laptop through a ethernet cable.

The Pi has a static IPv4 address. I am able to connect through SSH with it over the ethernet cable. For this I have to make a static IP at the laptop for the ethernet connection. Then I can connect over putty via SSH.

In my opinion I have to make a static IP at the laptop for the ethernet connection with the Pi. But then I am not anymore able to share the wlan.

I also followed this video but it wasn't that helpful because I have a static IP on my Pi that I want to keep.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U64YMItC5jc

Can someone also explain the difference between the right click on wlan -> properties -> sharing -> enable "allow the network user to connect through this internet connection"

and:

click on wlan and on ethernet, then right click -> Bridge Connection

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I found from testing the different options myself;

> 'Sharing' the connections means that the attached device will send packets to your computer using it's static IP. Then your laptop proceeds to do the same thing a NAT router would do: translate the Pi's static IP to whatever your laptop's IP is.

> 'Bridging' the connections means that your laptop will act as a network switch and therefore requires the Pi to either get an IP from your router's dhcp server, or be statically assigned one. Therefore your Pi can be seen by other devices on the network.

To summarise, 'Bridging' makes your Pi visible to other devices on your network and it has it's own IP. Whilst in 'Sharing' The Pi shares your laptop's IP and is therefore not visible to the rest of the network.

when connecting the devices with bridging you should not have to set a static IP for the laptop, only for the Pi.

Comment: Thank you for this! That gave me alot more understanding. But the problem is not solved i guess ;/. If i want to ssh via putty over the ethernet i need a static ip for the ethernet connection on my laptop otherwise i am not able to connect to the pi.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can EITHER connect to the Pi using `ssh` etc OR share the laptop internet connection not BOTH. (Technically this is not strictly correct, but it is very complex.)

You can use the Pi (through ICS on the laptop) at times, then turn ICS off to to use the laptop to connect to the Pi at other times.

Comment: You don't need static IP address. `ssh pi@hostname.local` default hostname `rasbperrypi` ) should let you connect (on a direct connection or local network)